# Efficient way to get the row number in a ordered CSV file that is higher than a specific unix timestamp

Tags: python, csv, search, pandas

I have a very big CSV file in the format where the first column is a `unix timestamp` already sorted from lowest to highest.

```
1461568570,2977.320000000000,0.032000000000
1461568570,2977.320000000000,0.076000000000
1461568570,2977.320000000000,0.076000000000
1461568569,2977.050000000000,0.050000000000
1461568569,2977.050000000000,0.050000000000
1461568569,2977.300000000000,0.021900000000
1461568569,2977.310000000000,0.021900000000
1461568569,2977.320000000000,0.050000000000
1461568423,2978.510000000000,0.500000000000
1461568421,2977.920000000000,0.023300000000
1461568421,2977.920000000000,0.010900000000
1461568421,2977.910000000000,0.165800000000
```

And I want to import the data into a pandas dataframe, but I want to restrict it to a subset of the data.

Now, pandas `read_csv` has the `skiprows` and `skipfooter` options where I can tell him to retrieve data only after a certain point row in the CSV file. But I want to specify the row number to start to read from to only catch the rows after a certain `unix timestamp` (so basically the line number of the 1st line that starts with a `unix timestamp` equal or higher than `1461568423` for example).

What would be an efficient to do this?

Comment: Is it a fixed width file? All the lines the same length? If so then you can use low-level file seek operations to jump to any given line, then its just a binary search algorithm...

Comment: @Spacedman no, the lines are of different lengths unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC then you can do something like the following:

```
In [47]:
line=0
chunksz=3
for chunk in pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None, names = ['timestamp','val1','val2'], chunksize=chunksz):
    if len(chunk[chunk['timestamp'] == 1461568423]) > 0:
        line += chunk[chunk['timestamp'] == 1461568423].index[0]
        break
    else:
        line += chunksz
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None, names = ['timestamp','val1','val2'], skiprows=line)

Out[47]:
    timestamp     val1    val2
0  1461568423  2978.51  0.5000
1  1461568421  2977.92  0.0233
2  1461568421  2977.92  0.0109
3  1461568421  2977.91  0.1658
```

Here we set a line counter to 0 and a nominal chunksz, we iterate over the chunks until we find a match and then we use this as the param value for skiprows. This should be fast as we can set a large chunksize and keep skipping chunks where the row isn't found

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the example, but this way we are still reading the all file up to the point we should start importing into Pandas right?

Comment: We only read a chunk size on each iteration, once we find the appropriate line number to read from we break from the loop and read the file from that point, as `read_csv` is fast it should find the desired row pretty quickly

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use preprocessing with `get_row` which return number of row with `timestamp` and it is use for parameter `skiprows` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

#preprocessing
def get_row(data):
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            if row[0] == data:
                return i

print get_row('1461568423')
8

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=get_row('1461568423'), header=None,names=['a','b','c'])
print df
            a        b       c
0  1461568423  2978.51  0.5000
1  1461568421  2977.92  0.0233
2  1461568421  2977.92  0.0109
3  1461568421  2977.91  0.1658
```

Comment: Well, this is the solution I though about 1st, but this way I would have to go trough all the file 1st and that's that part I want to do in a more efficient way.

Comment: Hmmm, I think without preprocessing it is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Note: in the example you've provided, timestamps are ordered from the highest to the lowest.

Considering that you have a csv file like:

```
timestamp
15
14
13
...
2
1
```

You can read it in chunks (`pd.read_csv` is having such option):

```
import pandas as pd

LIMIT_TIMESTAMP = 5

df_reader = pd.read_csv('data.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=3)
df = pd.DataFrame()

for chunk in df_reader:
    if chunk['timestamp'].min() < LIMIT_TIMESTAMP:
        chunk = chunk[chunk['timestamp'] > LIMIT_TIMESTAMP]
        df = pd.concat([df, chunk])
        break

    df = pd.concat([df, chunk])

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Results in:

```
   timestamp
0          15
1          14
2          13
3          12
4          11
5          10
6           9
7           8
8           7
9           6
```

You do not have to double read the file. Just read in chunks of sensible size and stop reading after getting to the moment when you've reached you timestamp. And filter obsolete rows from the last chunk.